# Asynchronous Client Socket: How to pass additional data to server?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I am studying the MSDN example code of using asynchronous client-server sockets. I understand how this goes when new connection of client is made.

But how in case when client is already connected, and wants to pass some new data to the server (or to other clients)?

This is what I have so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    AsynchronousClient ac;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonLogin.Enabled = false;
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(CreatingConnection)).Start();
    }

    private void CreatingConnection()
    {
        ac = new AsynchronousClient();
        ac.SendingMessage += (msg) => AC_SendingMassage(msg);
        ac.StartClient();
    }

    private void AC_SendingMassage(string message)
    {
        listBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { listBox1.Items.Add(message); });
    }

    private void buttonData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = textBox1.Text;
        //TODO:
        //how to send data from here (including whats in textBox)??
    }
}
```

And this is the code (2 classes) from msdn`s example (incluidng only for client):

```
public class StateObject
{
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousClient
{
    public event Action<string> SendingMessage;
    // The port number for the remote device.
    private const int port = 11000;

    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    // The response from the remote device.
    private string response;

    public void StartClient()
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.
        try
        {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
            string ip = "192.168.1.101";
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            // Send test data to the remote device.
            Send(client, "This is a test<EOF>");
            sendDone.WaitOne();

            // Receive the response from the remote device.
            Receive(client);
            receiveDone.WaitOne();

            // Write the response to the console.
            SendingMessage(string.Format("Response received : {0}", response));

            // Release the socket.
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SendingMessage(e.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            //Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}", client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            SendingMessage(string.Format("Socket connected to {0}", client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()));

            // Signal that the connection has been made.
            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            SendingMessage(e.Message);
        }
    }

    private void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SendingMessage(e.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                // Get the rest of the data.
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                }
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SendingMessage(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Send(Socket client, string data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            //Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);
            SendingMessage(string.Format("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent));
            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SendingMessage(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

--
Up there is a click event of buttonData, which one I wanna use for passing data to server.
I would like to know which method to call to pass new data when already connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would send data using the `Send` method. However, this sample code looks like it was really just meant to show you how some of these asynchronous methods work. The `StartClient` method closes everything out, which is probably not what you would want to do. You will likely need to write your own code to do this.